# FlowPlayer + RMTP

Tags: javascript, rtmp, flowplayer

Having difficulty with getting Flowplayer to work nicely with RTMP.

This is currently my setup:

JS

```
$f("flashFallback", "/uploadedFiles/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf", {
    key: '#mykey',
    clip: {
        url: 'myVid',
        provider: 'rtmp'
    },
    plugins: {
        rtmp: {
            url: '/uploadedFiles/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://downloads.mysite.com/flash_video/'
        }
    }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="flashFallback"></div>
```

My file paths are working fine, I can access them through other flv video players, but it's giving me the following error

201, Unable to load stream or clip file, connection failed, clip: '[Clip] myVid"

The server that the file is coming from runs Adobe FMS, can normally be accessed through HTTPS...not sure what else to give for details and I can't show an example as it's on a pre server and contains some...sensitive information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RTMP plugin documentation](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html) says:

> Adobe's Flash Media Server does not like the file extension in the clip's URL so you should not include it in the value. For example, just use url: 'metacafe' even when the file is actually named 'metacafe.flv'.

Despite that, I have seen streams sometimes only working with extension added and other times with extension prepended like `flv:myvid`. But this was more a problem of `f4v` or `mp4`.

You say, your server is accessable via HTTPS. If it's also via HTTP try to use `rtmpt` as protocol in your `netConnectionUrl`.

If all that does not work, try a minimized setup with free Flowplayer and try URLs from Flowplayer homepage. If they work and yours don't, consider this as a configuration problem of your FMS.

Comment: Thanks man. I have tried stripping out the extension first, and then adding it because I saw examples in other places that were using it without issue...I'll try that rtmpt protocol instead and cross my fingers. Cheers.